# Google Chrome keeps session variables after browser close

Tags: asp.net, security, google-chrome, session-state

I am using asp.net forms version 4 and using the built in FormsAuthentication.
I have selected to not persist the User.

```
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userIAmUsing, false);
```

When I close the browser in IE and Firefox. My session variables are destroyed and I am asked to re-login when I return to the page. However, in my Chrome settings I have the "Continue where I left off" setting checked. When I close the browser in Chrome, it is persisting the cookie against my (the developer's) wishes. In fact, even after I have logged out of my machine, the session is persisted. 
That being the situation, does anyone know of any thing that I can do as a developer to override this behavior and not allow the session to persist after browser close? In other words, can I make Chrome behave exactly like other browsers even if the user has checked that setting?

Comment: This came up today for me.  I found the discussion on the official [Chrome bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513) pretty interesting.  You can see [Google's official response](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513#c28) about half way down.  Evidently, they won't be fixing this.  As developers, I think our hands are tied.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies and sessions both have timeouts. You can set the timeouts to be short so Chrome wont try to reuse them after their time is up.

- [Set the timeout for .net session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Set the timeout for a cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That is something I could do but that opens another can of worms in that I now have people who this doesn't apply who are  having to re-login because I had to change the timeout to a short amount of time. I am really looking for a way to set something, kind of like a robots.txt file, that tells Chrome not to persist these cookies so that everyone plays by the same rules, not really changing everyone's rules to play with Google.

Comment: The .NET session is has a sliding expiration, meaning as long as the user is active, the expiration will continue to get pushed back. When they are inactive, it will not be pushed back and therefore expire after the timeout.

Comment: See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx

Comment: Sliding expiration doesn't solve the issue, it only makes the problem less likely. The main point is I can't tell the difference between "user A who closed their browser and user B opened it 1 minute later" vs."user A who waits 1 minute until his next click." I tried this with our company web mail selecting public computer and the problem is still there. So this opens a security issue that someone could use a public computer, click the setting, and then be a nice guy and hand over their computer to a victim. Then the hacker could take back the computer and have all of the victim's information.

Comment: In that case, I am not aware of anything you can do to secure that situation aside from training your users or not having a publicly accessible website. Note, I am not a security expert so perhaps someone else would.

Comment: I have been doing more testing also and found it is not an .net issue but the same hack is possible for any web app I have tried. In fact, you can have the history saved and actually pull up the page from the saved history if the session hasn't expired. So basically every app is not safe from this type of attack. I hope someone from Google reads this and sends out a hot fix because I feel it is really bad. The problem is that a user doesn't have to make the decision to do something risky but a novel use of technology allows this hack to appear. You can't blame the user for being unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explorer specific code as such. What you can do is, track the IP and the browser and then log off the user if request details changes.

Helpful?

Comment: Thanks, this is something I hadn't thought of but it doesn't solve my nightmare scenario. A student filling out an application at school with private information and another student coming back a couple of minutes later and is able to access their information because the student didn't remember to logout but just closed their browser. If google plays like everyone else, this isn't a problem but since it does not it is liability for me. And I hate to change everyone for one player because that makes me feels like IE6 all over again.

Comment: Perfect justification. But due to some hackers, you put high security and you too would agree that it puts some performance toll on that. Just try to put it in the module and reject the request. You can use load balancers if its hampering app performance. Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to manually try and delete the cookie in the unload handler;

```
$(window).unload(function () { /* delete session cookie */ } );
```